# Networkx: Inverted index on node attributes

Tags: python, networkx

I have a graph like the following:

```
P=nx.Graph()
P.add_node('node1',at=5)
P.add_node('node2',at=5)
P.add_node('node3',at=6)
```

I would like to access all nodes with at=5, without having to run across all nodes (so without list comprehension or for). IE, I would like an inverted index on attribute values.

I could add a dictionary, and fill it every time I create a new node (that's currently how I solve this problem) but I am wondering if there is a less artisanal and error-prone (and more efficient) way to do this

```
at_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)
at_dict[5].add('node1')
at_dict[5].add('node2')
at_dict[6].add('node3')
```

Note that I need to use a graph because I have to do some clustering on the nodes (so I cannot completely change my data structure)

Comment: Why not overriding the `Graph` class to add your dict inside it, and do whatever additional work you need on it when calling `add_node`?

Comment: Why not use a generator? `((node,data) for node, data in P.nodes(data=True) if data['at'] == 5)`

Comment: The only suggestion I would do differently is to wait until the graph is completely generated and then create your defaultdict in a loop at the end.  @Adonis's solution should work as long as you ensure that when you add a node it's always done with `add_node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a possibility you can subclass `nx.Graph` the following way:

```
class MyGraph(nx.Graph):

    def __init__(self, data=None, **attr):
        super().__init__(data, **attr)
        self.at_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)

    def add_node(self, n, attr_dict=None, **attr):
        super().add_node(n, attr_dict=attr_dict, **attr)
        self.at_dict[attr.get("at")].add(n)
```

Then you can use it like that:

```
P=MyGraph()
P.add_node('node1', at=5)
P.add_node('node2', at=5)
P.add_node('node3', at=6)
P.at_dict[5]
>>>{'node1', 'node2'}
```

P.S: Of course you'll have to override other methods such as `remove_node` so that your dict stays coherent. To override with the correct parameters, see this link for the source of the `nx.Graph` class: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/classes/graph.html

Answer (score 0):

### Get nodes by attribute value

A graph is a `dict` of `dict` in `networkx`. You can define the following function:

```
def get_nodes_by_attribute(G, att):
    return [k for k,v in G.nodes(data=True) if list(v.values())[0] == att]

get_nodes_by_attribute(P, 5)
```

[out]:

```
['node1', 'node2']
```

### Alternative 1: using `get_node_attributes()` from networkx

```
[k[0] for k in nx.get_node_attributes(P, 'at').items() if k[1] == 5]
```

[out]:

```
['node1', 'node2']
```

However, from the [source](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/classes/function.html#get_node_attributes) code it seems it's still a `dict` comprehension.

### Alternative 2: create a reversed index

Converting `dict`to a list of tuple:

```
tpl = [(k,v) for k,v in nx.get_node_attributes(P, 'at').items()]
# reverse the tuples
l = [x[::-1] for x in tpl]
```

Create a reversed `dict`:

```
d = {}
for elem in l:
    key = elem[0]
    if key in d:
        val = d[key]
        val.append(elem[1])
        d[key] = val
    else:
        d[key] = [elem[1]]
d
```

[out]:

```
{5: ['node1', 'node2'], 6: ['node3']}
```

Comment: It would work if the OP didn't mention in his query: "without list comprehension or for"

Comment: You are right. I updated with the creation of a reversed index.

Comment: I forget to mention that I need an "online" dictionary, that could be accessible even if I did not finished adding all the nodes